# ProgressBar in same relative layout as MapView: invisible unless MapView is visible

Tags: android, google-maps

So here is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/TransparentBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_map"
        android:visibility="invisible"
/>
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerprogress"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout.

In code, I load bunch of data and when its loaded, I hide ProgressBar (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`) and show MapView (`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`)

Problem being, unless MapView is `View.VISIBLE`, the ProgressBar is not shown. If I do not hide it, it appears as soon as I set MapView to visible.

Anybody has any suggestion on what is going on?

to answer on setVisibility:

```
public void onDataUpdate(JSONObject data) {
    ... work on data....
    mv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

basically thats it.

View initialization:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);

    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_map);
    //This is workaround to show at least anything to user while data is being loaded.
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    //However, loading spinner inside the ProgressDialog is invisible as well unless MapView is showing.
    pd.setTitle(R.string.map_is_loading);
    pd.show();
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinnerprogress);
    mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_map);
    mv.getMapAsync(this); //data will be loaded after getMapAsync()
    mv.onCreate(b);
    buildingLocation = new LatLng(
            getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("building_lat"),
            getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("building_lng")
    );
    polyline = getIntent().getExtras().getString("polyline");
    name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("building_name");
    address = getIntent().getExtras().getString("building_addr");


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

Themes:

```
    <style name="TransparentBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ba864c</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_general_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonThing</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/pink_app_color</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: is it possible that your progress bar is the same color as the background and you can't see it? also, post all your `setVisibility` code.

Comment: nope, its color is not same as background. Also updated the post with setVisibilities.

Comment: not seeing anything wrong. can you post your code where you're initializing the views?

Comment: maybe try `visibility="gone"` instead of `visibility="invisible"`

Comment: in that case its the same, @Panczur.

Comment: @ono, doing. Also will add theme information.

Comment: Not sure here. Everything seems right. Try with just a View instead of a ProgressBar and set a height and width to something like 100dp with a color contrasting your background and see if it still happening. Isolate the issue. Also, try a vertical LinearLayout. It won't look right since it will be at the bottom but if it works then something is going on with the RelativeLayout. Try removing the styling as well or `fitsSystemWindow`